# List<T> find index of GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game with turn-based combat.

For the combat i am pulling between 1-3 monsters and then placing them. The monsters are GameObjects.

I then put the monsters in a List so i can check their position from left-right. (left being index 0 and right being index 2 if there is 3 monsters ofc)

My only problem is getting the index of the GameObject..

This bit of code is on my CombatMainController.cs

```
void createMonster(){

        float numberOfMobs = Random.Range (1, 4);
        print (numberOfMobs);

        if (numberOfMobs > 2) {
            monsterStartpointX = -4f;
        } 
        else if (numberOfMobs > 1) {
            monsterStartpointX = -2f;
        } 
        else {
            monsterStartpointX = 0f;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMobs; i++) {
            randomMonster = Random.Range(0, monsters.Count);
            GameObject monster = Instantiate(monsters[randomMonster], Vector3.up, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            aliveMonsters.Add(monster);
            Vector3 temp = monster.transform.position;
            temp.x = monsterStartpointX;
            temp.y = monsterStartpointY;
            monster.transform.position = temp;
            monsterStartpointX += 4f;
        }
    }

    public void removeMonster(GameObject gameObject){
        print (gameObject);
        aliveMonsters.Remove(gameObject);
    }
```

`print (gameObject)` returns: `Goblin(Clone) (UnityEngine.GameObject)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)` - which is the `GameObject` that is being clicked on.

But `aliveMonsters.Remove(gameObject);` does not remove said `GameObject`.

This is the code that is attached to the monster

```
void OnMouseUp(){
        OnClickGUI = !OnClickGUI;
        //Destroy (gameObject);
    }
    void OnGUI(){
        if (OnClickGUI) {
            Vector3 V = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(V.x - 50,Screen.height - V.y,100,30),"Attack")){
                takenDamage();
            }
        }
    }
    void takenDamage(){
        combatController.removeMonster (gameObject);
    }
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong and hope you can help me or atleast point me in a better direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MSDN you can read this about the [List.Remove Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If type `T` implements the `IEquatable<T>` generic interface, the equality comparer is the `Equals` method of that interface; otherwise, the default equality comparer is `Object.Equals`.

If neither `IEquatable<T>` is implemented by the game object nor `Object.Equals` is overridden then reference equality is used for the comparison and this one will never fail if the given object is really in the list. This is the default behavior of `Object.Equals`.

I could imagine that either a faulty `Object.Equals` override or `IEquatable<T>` implementations exists that makes the Remove method fail.

Another possibility is that you try to remove a **clone** of the game object. In that case reference equality cannot work! You could fix it by overriding the `Object.Equals` method and to make it compare object IDs. Or you could remove like this:

```
int index = aliveMonsters.FindIndex(m => m.ID == monster.ID);
if (index >= 0 ) {
    aliveMonsters.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

But in any case, make sure that there is really a problem with the list and not just with the game logic. The object might be removed from the list but not from the game.

Comment: I know the object isnt being removed from the game, because havent made it to that step yet.

What i want to do is to have a way of indexing the monsters so i can see which one is to the left (0) and which is to the right (2)

Comment: If they are in the list, they are indexed already: `var leftMonster = aliveMonsters[0]; var rightMonster = aliveMonsters[2];` or use `FindIndex` as shown in my answer.

Comment: I've found out the problem wasnt with the list at all, the problem was that when i sent my GameObject Info from my monster to my manager script, the list was empty even though i could see in the inspector that it was populated.. So the problem is solved now, sorry if my question wasnt too clear..

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like:

```
public void removeMonster(GameObject gameObject){
        print (gameObject);
        GameObject objToRemove = allMonsters.DefaultIfEmpty(null)
                                    .FirstOrDefault(f=>f.obj.ID=gameObject.ID);
        if (objToRemove!=null)
            aliveMonsters.Remove(objToRemove);
        else
            throw new Exception("That monster isn't in the list.")
    }
```